# Is it possible to run 2 Ender 3's off one power supply?

Tags: creality-ender-3, creality, skr-v1.4

I have 2 Ender 3's and I am limited to wall sockets to power both the printers at the same time. So I was wondering if it was possible to wire both the printers to a single PSU? As the printer uses a single xt60 connecter for power to the mainboard, so there is a spare screw terminal on the PUS where the xt60 for the other printer could be screwed in. I am just afraid if I run both printers off one PSU, I might see some magic smoke or else the psu may not be able to provide enough power for them both and may cause print/power failure.

Comment: BTW, welcome to 3D Printing Stack Exchange.  You should probably take the [tour] and look at the [FAQ], though you seem to have done pretty well for a first question.

Answer (score 3):

The heated bed alone draws 220 W of 24 V power, so I'm going to say no, you shouldn't attempt to run two Ender 3 machines from a single power supply.

Instead, because the whole machine only draws about 3.5 A at 115 V (or half that at 230 V), you should consider installing a power strip or (better) a small UPS to both power both machines from your existing outlet(s) and also protect the machines from power surges and short power interruptions.  You won't overload your outlets, and you won't risk burning out a power supply by drawing twice the power it's built to provide.

Comment: If you intended to run one or both without a heated bed though it might work fine.